# Where can I find generic animal sounds for a childrens game?

Tags: sound-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find free sound effects?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/where-can-i-find-free-sound-effects)

I'm making an iPad app for children and need some generic, high-quality animal sounds.

Any ideas where I can find some? The majority I've found so far have either had a lot of background noise or aren't a generic enough sound (Oo-oo for a monkey or a duck quacking...)

Thanks in advance. 
Sam

Answer (score 1):

The freesound site is pretty good:
http://www.freesound.org/

There is also findsounds:
http://www.findsounds.com/types.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this soundFX library: http://www.soundexmachina.com/animalfarm and hopefully, you might find something useful in there.

It's a free and premium library about farm animals, including sheep, goat, rooster, chicken, horse, turkey and much more.